# gnuplot png export

Tags: windows-xp, gnuplot

How to "export" a graph to png or something insertable in Word ? I know there are a dozen tutorials for this on the 'net, but I'm having trouble just finding a simple example.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for superuser.com. It isn't programming related.

Comment: @A. Levy - Then move it, if it makes you happy ... I've long since past the point of hoping that maniacs ( honorable exceptions excluded(!) ) on these sites will ever come to an agreement about what belongs where (and stick to it).

Comment: actually i use gnuplot to show my programs' outputs visually, i'm not sure it belongs to superuser

Comment: I did exactly that on Linux, except that I fed the commands in via stdin instead of using the -p switch. I used `set term x11 persist` to make the window stay. Maybe there's something similar for Windows? (And let's not forget that Linux is free to download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these;

Once you are happy with your plot, set your output terminal type to ``Postscript.''

> gnuplot> set terminal postscript

Graphics will be written in Postscript format, the language understood by our printers, instead of the format understood by the windowing system. Then specify a file name for your postscript output.

> gnuplot> set output 'myfile.ps'

Then write your plot to the file by replotting.

> gnuplot> replot

To send your Postscript file to the printer, use the lpr shell command, (**OPTIONAL**)

> $ lpr myfile.ps

If you would like to continue working with your plot in a graphics window, you will need to return the output and terminal settings to normal by typing

> gnuplot> set terminal x11
>
> gnuplot> set output

A great tutorial is [here](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html)

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but if I needed an output in PostScript format, I would've asked for such. I do not mean to print it at all. Just need to look at it, and insert it in some Word documents, neither which I can do with .ps (which is a dying format on win platforms).

Comment: i just write the print to use it optional, you can also easily make myfile.png, i work in Linux so i get use to write that, not a big deal.

Comment: Sorry. It's late and I need to get this working, and it's giving me headaches (therefore the crankyness). Anyway, I tried using "set output ...", but after plotting ("plot sin(x)") it just leaves me with an empty file (zero size). Do you know maybe what could cause that ?

Comment: i edited, now it works just for .ps. also you can use ghostview to see .ps in Windows OS.

Comment: I've changed my question and accepted this as an answer since I had to thank you somehow for your help. Posted the other part as a separate question ... thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

On windows, you can

> set terminal windows

for the output to a window. Next for png output,

> set terminal png

This should work on the native windows gnuplot binary.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output output.png
```

And gnuplot should write to a file called `output.png`.

Comment: Can you explain lines in your answer?

Comment: @Zulu I guess the first sets the terminal, the second on the output. Seriously, one doesn't need to explain everything ;) bao: You must put the file name in quotes.